# Converting WXpython Bitmap to an Image, then Back Again

Tags: python, image, bitmap, wxpython

I have a function that I use to create a rectangular bitmap, in WXPython. I'd like to convert it to an image. Then back to a bitmap. How would one go about this?

Snippet:

```
    def make_shape(self, w, h, r ):

        maskc = wx.Color(0, 0, 0)
        shownc = wx.Color(0, 0, 1)

        bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(w, h)
        dc = wx.MemoryDC(bitmap)

        # Fill
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(shownc))

        # Rounding
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(shownc))

        # Shape
        dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(0, 0, w, h, r)

        dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

        bitmap.SetMaskColour(maskc)

        return bitmap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)` and `wx.BitmapFromImage(image)`